# PHP include(): Use case for include from original script's PWD

Tags: php

When using PHP's `include()` and `require()` functions to include a file which in turn includes another file, the PWD (relative reference) for the second file's `include()` is the directory for the original script location (the first script in the stack as called by Apache), not for the current file. What is the design decision behind that, and what is the use-case?

For instance, suppose a generic database-connection class defined in `~/public_html/classes/database.php` which stores its configuration data (usernames, passwords) out of the web root in `~/config.php`. The author of the database configuration class would logically call the config file with the relative filename `../../config.php`. However, this does not work as expected because the PWD is not of the `database.php` file but rather of the file which included it, which could be `~/public_html/index.php`, `~/public_html/someDir/somePage.php` or elsewhere.

I know to work around this by getting the directory of the current file with `dirname(__FILE__)`. However, I cannot think of a single use case where I would want `require()` or `include()` to be relative to the original script location. What is the use case for it being as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `include()` and `require()` handle relative path the same as any other file access function like `fopen()`, `unlink()` and `mkdir()`.

Path are always relative to PWD regardless of the location of the script.

Take the following example into consideration:

*/home/foo/index.php* does

```
require_once('lib/maketest.php');
```

*/home/foo/lib/maketest.php* does

```
mkdir('test');
```

This will create the directory */home/foo/test* and **not** */home/foo/lib/test*.

---

I can image that this has chosen because a bash script that does `mkdir test` will also create the directory `$PWD/test` regardless of where the script is located.

Having `include()` following the same logic as other file access functions makes sense. Consider the following code:

```
if (file_exists('config.php')) include('config.php');
```

If paths in `include()` would be relative to `__DIR__` and paths in `file_exists()` to PWD the above code wouldn't work as expected.

Comment: I am addressing compound `include()`s, for which the PWD of the first `include()`ed file remains the same PWD as the original file. I have always found this an annoyance, and never a help.

Comment: @dotancohen I've rephrased the answer. Hope you understand the design considerations now. There is a logic behind it, even if you don't agree with the choice.

Answer (score 1):

PWD is short for Print Working Directory. Current working directory is abbreviated as CWD.
The CWD might change during the code execution and PHP doesn't necessarily have to include code from a local file path.

As you already knew, examining `__FILE__` together with `dirname()` is the correct solution to your problem. You should also be defining a constant with the root path of your application and use that throughout the code instead of relying on that the working directory stays the same.
The CWD will not even be the path of your script starting point in all situations.